# Bevel Problems, need assistance

Tags: bevel

[image]

Hi. Im using version 2.82.7 I believe. I want to put a bevel around the top edge of the letters all the way around the top edge, in which the edge and face move in towards the center like the cube on the right. I haven't been successful.

My first step was to add text, use a font, and make it look like I wanted. Then I converted it to a mesh, but I can't get the edge to bevel or scale in to the center?
thx

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what the text topology looks like in edit mode? If you look between both instances of the R and the E you can see there are overlapping faces, and I suspect there are more. Things like this confuse blender when it's trying to make calculations for things such as beveling, so it's important to have good underlying topology first (extruded text usually doesn't without some modification first). Also, you say you can't get it to bevel and scale towards the center - what is happening instead?

Comment: thanks for your time, please forgive the late reply, I decided to try something else. Thx

Comment: Text objects are generated with terrible topology, I'm guessing because they have to account for many different options and generate the mesh after the fact.  In almost every case I just delete all top and bottom faces and retopo to all quads.  Then most mesh operations should work normally.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if using the bevel modifier by itself works. Make sure your scale is applied as well.

If the bevel does work, you will need to create a vertex group with all the top faces of the text selected. You can then use that vertex group as a mask for the bevel modifier.

If the bevel modifier doesn't work, let me know and we can sort something out.

EDIT:

I did some experimentation, and it turns out that the text object in Blender has a bevel option! Simply just edit the bevel settings the way you want, then convert the text to mesh. You can then delete the bottom section of the text, re-extrude downwards, and voila!

[image]

The screenshot above is from Blender 2.92, and I see you're using 2.82. Most of the options should still be there, but if they aren't...

Then you'll have to retopologize your text and then apply a bevel modifier on that.

Comment: i am pretty sure, that this won't work. And i am pretty sure you never tried this with a font...And yes, i tried it. And it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Chris :). It's probably meant to be used on a mesh object, in which case it would work. The main problem with beveling converted text is messy topology.

Comment: @Jachym Michal:  think I understood. Of course - on an easy mesh object this can be done. But fonts aren‘t an „easy“ mesh object. They have a quite difficult geometry. And to be honest -  I tried it several times …I didn’t make it. Not to bevel that much and that it looks good.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I decided to try something else.